# Highcharts multiple x axes is hidden on zoom

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I used the multiple axes on the highchart
During Zoom operation the x values are getting hidden
I used linked to attribute also
[image: Original Image]

[image: X axes values hidden image]

[image: Sample code]

Comment: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before you post question in SO

Comment: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/3716 is still open issue

Comment: Recreate a live example of the problem on jsfiddle/etc. or at least share the code which allows to reproduce the issue.

Comment: code here  -  http://jsfiddle.net/hz0xkkr1/4/

Answer (score 1):

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kondaldurgam/hz0xkkr1/5/)

```
  zoomType: 'y',
```

zoomType: String

Decides in what dimensions the user can zoom by dragging the mouse. Can be one of x, y or xy.

**Try it:**

[None by default](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/chart/zoomtype-none/)

[x](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/chart/zoomtype-x/)

[y](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/chart/zoomtype-y/)

[xy](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/chart/zoomtype-xy/)

Answer (score 0):

I referred [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hz0xkkr1/4/) to figure out what's happening. I think, this behavior is not a bug/issue.

[This github issue](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/3716) mentioned in comments is not the problem here. Because what it is saying is to use `linkedTo: 0` which is already present in this example.

It actually depends on **how much area** and more importantly **from where to where** you select for zooming in. Let's see that by examples:

In the following image, **the rectangle signifies the width of one column**.

Now, **if you start your pinch from more than half of the width of any column or end the pinch after half of the width of a column, that column would be fully visible along with x-Axis labels**.

[image]

But, if you pinch any less, say from the middle of orange bar of first column, till middle of next column's blue bar, it's not going to show whole columns and hence it ends up with hidden x-Axis labels.